# Finding point in a plane at fixed distances from 2 other points in the plane

Tags: javascript, 3d, geometry

I have three 3D points defining a plane, P1(x1,y1,z1) P2(x2,y2,z3) and P3(x3,y3,z3). I need to find another point A on that plane which is L1 length from P1 and L2 length from P2 and closest to P3 (out of the 2 possible positions). I have found a solution for this in 2D (https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jr/2010/984823) but I am having difficulty extending it to 3D. I will be implementing this in JS. Any help would be appreciated!
[image]

```
function calculatePointFromLengths(p1,p2,l1,l2) {
let L = sqrt((p2.x-p1.x)*(p2.x-p1.x)+(p2.y-p1.y)*(p2.y-p1.y));
let angleP1P2 = Math.atan((p2.y-p1.y)/(p2.x-p1.x));
let theta1 = Math.acos(l1*l1+l2*l2-l2*l2)/(2*l1*L) + angleP1P2;

// now calculate the point using the angle

return( {
    x: p1.x + l1 * Math.cos(theta1);
    y: p1.y + l1 * Math.sin(theta1);
});
```

}

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I've added it for the 2d version now.

Answer (score 0):

Because you already have angle between P1A and P1P2 vectors

```
theta = Math.acos(l1*l1+l2*l2-l2*l2)/(2*l1*L)
```

You can take vector with direction of P1P2 and length l1

```
V = P1P2 * l1 / L  (do the same for every component)
```

and rotate it by angle `theta` around axis defined by vector product of `P1P2` and `P2P3`

```
axis = P1P2 x P2P3
```

and apply [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula), then get `A` point as `P1 + V_rotated`

Alternative way: write `A` in parametric coordinates

```
A = P1 + P1P2*u + P1P3*v
```

Substitute these coordinates into distance equations

```
l1^2 = (P1P2*u + P1P3*v)^2
l2^2 = (-P2+ P1 + P1P2*u + P1P3*v)^2
```

and solve this equation system for unknows `u,v`, choosing solution with `0<u,v<1, u+v<1` (to provide A inside triangle)

Answer (score 0):

I have used an answer from stack exchange in the mathematics group (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4548418/finding-point-in-a-plane-at-fixed-distances-from-2-other-points-in-the-plane) and coded it here with a demonstration:
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#UEQUG8#46